# JBoss 7.1: Remote Naming Exception While Logging Over JMS

Tags: java, logging, jms, jboss7.x, jndi

I have an application that logs to a JMS topic on a JBoss 7.1 server on a different machine (application code -> slf4j -> JDK logging -> JMS topic). The logging works with JBoss 6, but not JBoss 7.1. Instead I get a the following exception while looking up the JMS topic using JNDI:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create remoting connection [Root exception is     java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING]
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:36)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:121)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)
    at ...<JMS/JNDI util classes>...
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$7.run(LogManager.java:919)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.initializeGlobalHandlers(LogManager.java:911)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$900(LogManager.java:129)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.getHandlers(LogManager.java:1018)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:454)
    at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:588)
    at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.info(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:285)
    at my.application.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.IoFutureHelper.get(IoFutureHelper.java:89)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.NamingStoreCache.getRemoteNamingStore(NamingStoreCache.java:56)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getOrCreateCachedNamingStore(InitialContextFactory.java:166)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getOrCreateNamingStore(InitialContextFactory.java:139)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:104)
    ... 26 more
```

In other places in the application, I am **successfully** using the same classes and JNDI properties to look up JMS topics. Also, netcat is able to connect to the remote naming port (4447) on the JBoss server.

Any idea why this wouldn't work?

**EDIT: Here is my code creating the InitialContext**

```
final Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://192.168.xxx.xxx:4447");
props.put("java.naming.security.principal", "remote");
props.put("java.naming.security.credentials", "remotepwd");

InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(props);
```

**EDIT: Startup script call:**

bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.bind.address=192.168.xxx.xxx -Djboss.bind.address.management=192.168.xxx.xxx -Djboss.bind.address.unsecure=192.168.xxx.xxx --server-config=standalone-full.xml -b=192.168.xxx.xxx -bmanagement=192.168.xxx.xxx

Comment: Please post InitiatContext creation code.

Comment: Are Queues on same machine (or) different? Have you add -b binding and management interface settings to startup script?

Comment: I hadn't, but after I did, it still didn't work. I edited the post to show how I am calling the startup script.